# Trying to build the LEVMAR math library on a mac using the Accelerate Framework

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, lapack

I want build levmar-2.5 math library on a mac using the included Makefile.  It requires LAPACK,
another math library which is included in the Accelerate Framework.  I do not know how to modify
the Makefile to indicate the location of the library so that it builds correctly.  There is a
libLAPACK.dylib in the framework.  Ultimately, I will want to use this library to build another library.  Also I am not sure if there will be a problem mixing .so and .dylib dynamic libraries.
Thank you.

The project is located at [levmar](http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/).

Here is the Makefile:

```
#
# Unix/Linux GCC Makefile for Levenberg - Marquardt minimization
# Under windows, use Makefile.vc for MSVC
#

CC=gcc
CONFIGFLAGS=#-ULINSOLVERS_RETAIN_MEMORY
#ARCHFLAGS=-march=pentium4 # YOU MIGHT WANT TO UNCOMMENT THIS FOR P4
CFLAGS=$(CONFIGFLAGS) $(ARCHFLAGS) -O3 -funroll-loops -Wall #-ffast-math #-pg
LAPACKLIBS_PATH=/usr/local/lib # WHEN USING LAPACK, CHANGE THIS TO WHERE YOUR COMPILED LIBS ARE!
LDFLAGS=-L$(LAPACKLIBS_PATH) -L.
LIBOBJS=lm.o Axb.o misc.o lmlec.o lmbc.o lmblec.o lmbleic.o
LIBSRCS=lm.c Axb.c misc.c lmlec.c lmbc.c lmblec.c lmbleic.c
DEMOBJS=lmdemo.o
DEMOSRCS=lmdemo.c
AR=ar
RANLIB=ranlib
LAPACKLIBS=-llapack -lblas -lf2c # comment this line if you are not using LAPACK.
                             # On systems with a FORTRAN (not f2c'ed) version of LAPACK, -lf2c is
                             # not necessary; on others, -lf2c is equivalent to -lF77 -lI77

#LAPACKLIBS=-L/usr/local/atlas/lib -llapack -lcblas -lf77blas -latlas -lf2c # This works with   the ATLAS updated lapack and Linux_P4SSE2
                                    # from   http://www.netlib.org/atlas/archives/linux/

#LAPACKLIBS=-llapack -lgoto2 -lpthread -lf2c # This works with GotoBLAS
                                         # from http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/research-development /tacc-projects/

#LAPACKLIBS=-L/opt/intel/mkl/8.0.1/lib/32/ -lmkl_lapack -lmkl_ia32 -lguide -lf2c # This works with MKL 8.0.1 from
                   # http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/perflib/mkl/index.htm

LIBS=$(LAPACKLIBS)

all: liblevmar.a lmdemo

liblevmar.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(AR) crv liblevmar.a $(LIBOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) liblevmar.a

lmdemo: $(DEMOBJS) liblevmar.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEMOBJS) -o lmdemo -llevmar $(LIBS) -lm

lm.o: lm.c lm_core.c levmar.h misc.h compiler.h
Axb.o: Axb.c Axb_core.c levmar.h misc.h
misc.o: misc.c misc_core.c levmar.h misc.h
lmlec.o: lmlec.c lmlec_core.c levmar.h misc.h
lmbc.o: lmbc.c lmbc_core.c levmar.h misc.h compiler.h
lmblec.o: lmblec.c lmblec_core.c levmar.h misc.h
lmbleic.o: lmbleic.c lmbleic_core.c levmar.h misc.h

lmdemo.o: levmar.h

clean:
    @rm -f $(LIBOBJS) $(DEMOBJS)

cleanall: clean
    @rm -f lmdemo
    @rm -f liblevmar.a

depend:
    makedepend -f Makefile $(LIBSRCS) $(DEMOSRCS)

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend depends on it.
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `-framework Accelerate` to gcc. You also need to`#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>`. Details are [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/LAPACK.7.html).

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I was able to build the library as well as the library that depends on levmar.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's the makefile that will work:

```
#
# Unix/Linux GCC Makefile for Levenberg - Marquardt minimization
# Under windows, use Makefile.vc for MSVC
#

CC=gcc
CONFIGFLAGS=#-ULINSOLVERS_RETAIN_MEMORY
#ARCHFLAGS=-march=pentium4 # YOU MIGHT WANT TO UNCOMMENT THIS FOR P4
CFLAGS=$(CONFIGFLAGS) $(ARCHFLAGS) -O3 -funroll-loops -Wall #-ffast-math #-pg
#LAPACKLIBS_PATH=/usr/local/lib # WHEN USING LAPACK, CHANGE THIS TO WHERE YOUR COMPILED LIBS ARE!
LDFLAGS=-L. # for non-OSX, add: -L$(LAPACKLIBS)
LIBOBJS=lm.o Axb.o misc.o lmlec.o lmbc.o lmblec.o lmbleic.o
LIBSRCS=lm.c Axb.c misc.c lmlec.c lmbc.c lmblec.c lmbleic.c
DEMOBJS=lmdemo.o
DEMOSRCS=lmdemo.c
AR=ar
RANLIB=ranlib

LAPACKLIBS=-framework Accelerate #This works for OSX where the SDK is installed.

LIBS=$(LAPACKLIBS)

all: liblevmar.a lmdemo

liblevmar.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(AR) crv liblevmar.a $(LIBOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) liblevmar.a

lmdemo: $(DEMOBJS) liblevmar.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEMOBJS) -o lmdemo -llevmar $(LIBS) -lm

lm.o: lm.c lm_core.c levmar.h misc.h compiler.h
Axb.o: Axb.c Axb_core.c levmar.h misc.h
misc.o: misc.c misc_core.c levmar.h misc.h
lmlec.o: lmlec.c lmlec_core.c levmar.h misc.h
lmbc.o: lmbc.c lmbc_core.c levmar.h misc.h compiler.h
lmblec.o: lmblec.c lmblec_core.c levmar.h misc.h
lmbleic.o: lmbleic.c lmbleic_core.c levmar.h misc.h

lmdemo.o: levmar.h

clean:
    @rm -f $(LIBOBJS) $(DEMOBJS)

cleanall: clean
    @rm -f lmdemo
    @rm -f liblevmar.a

depend:
    makedepend -f Makefile $(LIBSRCS) $(DEMOSRCS)

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend depends on it.
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas. It works great on OSX. Any clues on how to make it work on iOS?

Comment: With "ARCHFLAGS=-arch armv6 -arch armv7", the make process fails with "gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1': execvp: No such file or directory"

Comment: Started a brand new question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074096/how-to-build-an-iphone-static-library-based-on-a-makefile