# How to build an iPhone static library based on a Makefile?

Tags: c, ios, build, makefile

I have managed to build a static C library on OSX using `make` on the command line.

I have tried to use the same Makefile (with `ARCHFLAGS=-arch armv6 -arch armv7`) to build a static library for iOS, but it fails with:

```
gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I guess it is not working because I'm using the OSX SDK make instead of a some part of the iOS SDK. Any clues?

N.B. For more details on the library in question (levmar) and for the Makefile, please refer to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539735/trying-to-build-the-levmar-math-library-on-a-mac-using-the-accelerate-framework/6063585#6063585).

Comment: did you get this working? I tried adding CC=llvm-gcc-4.2 and ARCHFLAGS=-arch armv6 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s but got errors: llvm-gcc-4.2  -arch armv6 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -O3 -funroll-loops -Wall    -c -o lm.o lm.c
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory - when removing archflags it compiled fine (but for 386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find:

- the location of the iOS compiler
- the command line options that are used in the command line invocation

The easiest way is to create a test iPhone/iPad app in XCode, build it, and then look at the build log to find how XCode invokes the compiler.

Comment: I tried changing the cc= directive to clang but wasn't able to compile for arm. got errors clang  -arch armv7 -O3 -funroll-loops -Wall    -c -o lm.o lm.c
In file included from lm.c:26:
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:67:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:10: fatal error: 'arm/_types.h' file not found
#include "arm/_types.h" . any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make an Xcode project and invoke Xcode on the command line or from a script? If you don't want the fuss of maintaining an Xcode project, an easier approach might be to use CMake to generate an Xcode project and then invoke Xcode on the command line or from a script. This way you can stay in the text-file and script domain the whole time.