# Building levmar on Mac Yosemite

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

Hi I want to build levmar (Levenberg Marquardt) C++ library on Mac. It comes with a makefile (http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/index.html) but I have some questions about how to use it on Mac (Yosemite)

(1) The gcc I have currently installed on Mac is in fact clang. I can confirm this if I run gcc -v on the terminal. Should I install proper gcc before building levmar?

(2) Levmar recommends using LAPACK (Linear Algebra Library). Again, I have been reading on another stack overflow post ([Trying to build the LEVMAR math library on a mac using the Accelerate Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539735/trying-to-build-the-levmar-math-library-on-a-mac-using-the-accelerate-framework)) that they were using Mac OS Accelerate framework that comes with LAPACK. Does anyone know how do I get that on yosemite? Or should I be building LAPACK standalone on mac first?

Thank you

Comment: The clang compiler should be fine, and the Accelerate framework should already be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Makefile from [Trying to build the LEVMAR math library on a mac using the Accelerate Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539735/trying-to-build-the-levmar-math-library-on-a-mac-using-the-accelerate-framework) posted by Janos and it works for levmar-2.6 using clang and Accelerate framework.